# Keep the coroutine context when a block under withContext calls another suspend block

Tags: kotlin

When using `withContext` in Kotlin, how to keep the new context after calling another suspend function?

For example:
https://pl.kotl.in/fkrnEkYZP

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val anotherBlock = suspend {
        assertSame(Dispatchers.IO, coroutineContext[CoroutineDispatcher], "current CoroutineDispatcher should be still Dispatchers.IO")
        // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: current CoroutineDispatcher should be still Dispatchers.IO. Expected &amp;lt;Dispatchers.IO&amp;gt;, actual &amp;lt;BlockingEventLoop@6863cde3&amp;gt; is not same.
    }
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        assertSame(Dispatchers.IO, coroutineContext[CoroutineDispatcher], "current CoroutineDispatcher should be Dispatchers.IO")
        anotherBlock()
    }
}
```

Why is the `coroutineContext` in `anotherBlock` different with the parent one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not looking at the actual current coroutine context when doing the assert in the suspend lambda, you're in fact capturing the `coroutineContext` from `runBlocking`'s `CoroutineScope`.

The reason why it works in `withContext` directly is because `withContext` provides a `CoroutineScope` as `this` - which shadows the one given by `runBlocking`, so luckily you get the correct one.

To avoid this pitfall (which occurs regularly when using both `suspend` functions and `CoroutineScope`), you should use [currentCoroutineContext()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/current-coroutine-context.html) when you want to know the coroutine context in which the current code is executing, which is your case here.

If you do this, you'll see the dispatcher is properly inherited:

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val anotherBlock = suspend {
        assertSame(Dispatchers.IO, currentCoroutineContext()[CoroutineDispatcher], "current CoroutineDispatcher should be still Dispatchers.IO in suspend lambda")
    }
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        assertSame(Dispatchers.IO, coroutineContext[CoroutineDispatcher], "current CoroutineDispatcher should be Dispatchers.IO")
        anotherBlock()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joffrey. Is it always recommended to use `currentCoroutineContext()` rather than `coroutineContext`?

Comment: @Clippit I would say it's a matter of what you want to express. I would recommend to use it every time you want to get the coroutine context of the currently executing code. The `coroutineContext` property of the `CoroutineScope` class could be useful for other things I imagine (never needed it myself to be honest), but I would only use it if I semantically want to access the context of a specific scope, not the "current" one. Regarding the implicit `coroutineContext` property inside `suspend` functions, I would just never use it to avoid confusion with the scope's property.

Answer (score 1):

`coroutineContext` is a property of CoroutineScope. Since your `anotherBlock` suspend function does not have a CoroutineScope receiver, you are calling `coroutineContext` on the scope of the `runBlocking` lambda, so it's getting the `runBlocking`'s dispatcher.

Change your declaration of the function to use extension function syntax instead of a lambda so it can have its own CoroutineScope.

```
suspend fun CoroutineScope.anotherBlock() {
    assertSame(Dispatchers.IO, coroutineContext[CoroutineDispatcher], "current CoroutineDispatcher should be still Dispatchers.IO")
    // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: current CoroutineDispatcher should be still Dispatchers.IO. Expected &amp;lt;Dispatchers.IO&amp;gt;, actual &amp;lt;BlockingEventLoop@6863cde3&amp;gt; is not same.
}
```